# How to print the sum of cell values as a string into a new column in pandas? (IF/ELSE)

Tags: python, pandas

I am beginner in Python and have the following df:

```
print(df)
>>>
NAME     KIDS     TEENS 
Steve     1         0  
John      0         1 
Peter     0         2
Frank     0         0
Jessica   1         0
Donny     0         0
```

My goal is to create a new column called "Children", which indicates - based on the values from the columns KIDS and TEENS - if the person has Children or not. My idea would be to use an IF-Statement.

IF "KIDS" + "TEENS" > 0 THEN CHILDREN "YES" ELSE "NO".

Is this a good approach and how can I achieve it?

The final result should looks something like this:

```
print(df)
>>>
NAME     KIDS     TEENS   CHILDREN
Steve     1         0       YES
John      0         1       YES
Peter     0         2       YES
Frank     0         0       NO
Jessica   1         0       YES
Donny     0         0       NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
df['CHILDREN'] = (df['KIDS'] | df['TEENS']).astype(bool)
```

Because `0` is Falsey and any number is True, this will be `False` if both are `0` and `True` if either `KIDS` or `TEENS` is > 0.

I would recommend using boolean values (True/False) to represent this, but if you want the strings you could follow this with `df['CHILDREN'].replace({True:'Yes', False: 'No'})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['CHILDREN'] = np.where(df.KIDS + df.TEENS > 0, 'YES', 'NO')
```

Output:

```
>>> df

      NAME  KIDS  TEENS CHILDREN
0    Steve     1      0      YES
1     John     0      1      YES
2    Peter     0      2      YES
3    Frank     0      0       NO
4  Jessica     1      0      YES
5    Donny     0      0       NO
```

Setup used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['Steve', 'John', 'Peter', 'Frank', 'Jessica', 'Donny'],
    'KIDS': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    'TEENS': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
df['Children'] = (df['KIDS'] + df['TEENS']).astype(bool)
```

OR

```
df['Children'] =  df.sum(axis=1).astype(bool)
```

```
    NAME    KIDS    TEENS   Children
0   Steve     1     0       True
1   John      0     1       True
2   Peter     0     2       True
3   Frank     0     0       False
4   Jessica   1     0       True
5   Donny     0     0       False
```